# How to get data when group by a column?

Tags: php, joomla

I have a sample data:

```
mobile(id, name, os)
      (1, "samsung 1", "android")
      (2, "samsung 2", "android")
      (3, "iPhone 3", "OS")
      (4, "iPhone 4", "OS")
      (5, "samsung 3", "android")
```

And query:

```
$db =& JFactory::getDBO(); 
$query = "SELECT id, name, os
          FROM `mobile` order by os";
$db->setQuery($query);        
$rows = $db->loadObjectList(); 
$i=0;
$data = array();
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    if(empty($data[$row->os])) {
        $data[$row->os] = array();
    }
    if(empty($data[$row->os][$row->name])) {
        $data[$row->os][$row->name] = array();
    }
    $data[$row->os][$row->name] = $row->id;
}
<?php foreach ($data as $os => $names) {?>
<li>
    <?php echo $os; ?>
    <ul>
        <?php
        foreach ($names as $name => $id) {
            ?>
            <li>
                <?php echo $name; ?>
            </li>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
    </ul>
</li>               
<?php $i++; }?>
```

when i run code, result not show on this:

```
android
-samsung 1
-samsung 2
-samsung 3
OS
-iPhone 3
-iPhone 4
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Why didn't you use ORDER BY os?

Answer (score 0):

```
$data[$row->os][$row->name] = $row->id
```

should be

```
$data[$row->os][$row->id] = $row->name
```

(and accordingly change below)

You keep overwriting `$data["android"]["Samsung"]` with `1, 2, 3, 4`; index by unique things like IDs, not by names which can and do repeat.

EDIT: I see you initialise `$data[$row->os][$row->id]` to be an array, but you then overwrite that value with `$row->name`; and you don't loop over it; so it's useless. That would be one way as well, but less efficient, because more unnecessary looping.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
$data[$row->os][$row->name] = $row->id;
```

To this:

```
$data[$row->os][$row->name][] = $row->id;
```

The first replaces an array with a single item. The second pushes an item onto the array.